# Image in uialertview...?

Tags: iphone, popup, uiimage, uialertview

I know this is frequently asked question that, how to display another control rather message in uiAlertView.
I have an app which have image in my view and when user tap on that image I want to enlarge it.
So, I have option that popup it in uialertview with same image with enlargement.
when I try it as well, but not with proper solution.

below is my code

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NULL message:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"GM00132002062125.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
CGFloat imageHeight = 250;
CGFloat imageWidth = imageHeight * image.size.width / image.size.height;
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(floor((284 - imageWidth)/2), 47, imageWidth, imageHeight);
[alert addSubview:imageView];
[alert show];
```

here I have to give \n\n for message,

[image]

If you can see it overlap on OK
if I give more \n in message

[image]

There is no particular solution for this

Thanks

Comment: Cant u reduce the size of the image ?

Comment: Actually on view image is in small size, when user tap on that image it have to be enlarge. And if I reduce popup image size, there's no use of it.

Comment: please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323557/image-in-uialertview

Comment: Thanks Midhun MP, as you can check I've already code same. Rather My code is more specific with image size.Already gone with this post. Not useful.

Comment: have tried changing the `y` or `height` for your image view frame?

Comment: Thanks nikita, but I think u not getin my point, height can be increased if image is big. So, there is not proper solution with this alert view...!?!

Answer (score 1):

use this bellow code...

```
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:setYourFrameHere];

    NSString *imgPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"GM00132002062125.png"]];
    UIImage *yourImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imgPath];
    [imageView setImage:yourImage];
    [yourImage release];
    [imgPath release];

    [alert addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];

    [alert show];
    [alert release];
```

**UPDATE:**

For center the image or some customview in our view i use this type of bellow code..try this...

```
myCustomView.frame = CGRectMake(floorf(backgroundView.size.width - customView.size.width / 2.0f), 0.0, myCustomView.size.widht, myCustomView.size.height);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Paras Joshi, but I think you've to check my code. It's much same as yours. Rather I just put proper size specifications.

Comment: try to center the image with my above code may be its work for you just use imageView to center in alertview just change some code.. and it will work..

Comment: Thanks, CGFloat imageHeight = 250;
CGFloat imageWidth = imageHeight * image.size.width / image.size.height;
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(floor((284 - imageWidth)/2), 47, imageWidth, imageHeight);
with this I'm doing same thing.

Comment: @Deer why you give this \n more than time?? for get image center right??

Comment: that is not for image center that is for make space height wise for uialertview. and I'm not give 9 \n. That's just for example. And my meaning is not with this image only. Actually my image size can be more than this. In that situation our this code will not work. That's why I want some proper solution of this Paras.

Comment: ya ya now i understand that what you want.. here you see overlap the image with message box if you give more than \n and also image display out of uialertview if \n is lessthen the height of image,... right??

Comment: yes, this is just example through which I want to ask you that if my image size is 300x300. How can I use this code because here image height is more that uialertview height. Now got it...!?!

Comment: @Deer hey if you use custom popup instead of alertview then its also very useful and also easy to use for you..

Comment: with custom popup, you can't be sure that app will pass in app review, otherwise I already go with that option...!?!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22315/discussion-between-deer-and-paras-joshi)