# How to show the image via http url in AlertView in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uialertview, nsurl

I am developing in Objective-C , and I want to show the image via `http url` in `AlertView` ?

I already get the image url like:**`http://192.72.1.1/DCIM/100__DSC/SNAP0053.JPG`** , and convert the `NSURL` to `NSString`. But I can not show the image in AlertView , it is empty.

The code for convert the url to NSString and show in AlertView is like the following:

```
NSString *path = [url absoluteString];
NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: path]];
UIImage *Image=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Image" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

[imageView setImage:Image];

[alert addSubview:imageView];
[alert show];
```

But the AlertView did not show any image like the following picture. 
[image]

Did I missing something ?

**How to show the image via http url in AlertView in Objective-C ?**

Comment: You can add subview to `UIAlertView` since iOS7 (If my memory doesn't fail me). You have to use a custom `UIAlertView` (many project on GitHub that do the same behaviour)

Comment: have tried this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2323694? I think you not set its x,y,width and height property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant add image in AlertView.
It was possible prior to iOS 7.
You can create a custom AlertView and add image to it.

Also check out this

https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that. Write a custom control with `UIView` which imitate the behavior of `UIAlertView`.

Some suggestions:

1. Never use `addSubView` on `UIAlertView`.
2. `UIAlertView` is deprecated use `UIAlertController`.

Reference [UIAlertView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html):

1)

> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
>   must not be modified.

2)

> Important: UIAlertView is deprecated in iOS 8. (Note that
>   UIAlertViewDelegate is also deprecated.) To create and manage alerts
>   in iOS 8 and later, instead use UIAlertController with a
>   preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert.