# Adding UIImage to UIAlertView is not working as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage, uialertview

I am working on an app. I tried to add an UIIMage to UIAlertView using below code,

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Instruction"
                                                    message:@"Please TAP on Screen to Continue."
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, 50, 32, 32)];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pendingImg.png"];
[imageView setImage:img];
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
    [alert setValue:imageView forKey:@"accessoryView"];
}else{
    [alert addSubview:imageView];
}
[alert show];
```

My image is of dimension 32 × 32 pixels. I am getting the alert as shown,

[image: Alert]

Should I add constraints to this image? or anything else to be made?

Comment: You shouldn't generally mess around with the view heirachy of UIAlertView. It would be far safer, not to mention better to create your own alert style view.

Comment: Try changing the content mode of the imageView to aspect fit.

Comment: Check if it is working with  UIImageView's contentMode UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323557/is-it-possible-to-show-an-image-in-uialertview

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik My question is to make the image look normal, above post is to add image to UIAlertView

Comment: @WillForte - whats your image actual width and height

Comment: My image is of dimension 32 × 32 pixels....i mentioned that in post

Comment: @WillForte - check the updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set imageView `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`,

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Instruction"
                                                    message:@"Please TAP on Screen to Continue."
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, 50, 32, 32)];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pendingImg.png"];
 imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

[imageView setImage:img];
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
    [alert setValue:imageView forKey:@"accessoryView"];
}else{
    [alert addSubview:imageView];
}
[alert show];
```

[image]

Might be **Anbu.Karthik** suggested link comment also helpful for you.

Comment: if you are using lager size , it automaticaly fit in image view

Comment: imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit; was the culprit :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 UIAlertView* alert = [UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Instruction" message: @"Please TAP on Screen to Continue." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"no" otherButtonTitles:@"yes", nil];

    UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pendingImg.png"];
    UIImageView* imgview = [UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height)];
    [img setImage:imgMyImage];

    [alert setValue: imgview forKey:@"accessoryView"];
    [alert show];
```

Comment: It just adds image to UIAlertVIew, somehow I am getting that with my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Instruction" message: @"Please TAP on Screen to Continue." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"no" otherButtonTitles:@"yes", nil];

   UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"add.png"];
    UIImageView* imgview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height)];
    [imgview setImage:img];
    [alert setValue: imgview forKey:@"accessoryView"];
    [alert show];
}
```